# JS/TS : Assigning to Child class property all parent properties (static and instance variables)

Tags: typescript

```js
abstract class Base {
  // class methods
  public static findOne() {}
  public static findMany() {}

  // instance methods
  public save() {console.log('base save')}
}

class Child extends Base {
  // class methods
  public static basePolicy = ?
  
  // instance methods
  public basePolicy = ?

  // instance methods
  public save() {console.log('child save')}
}

// use basePolicy on static methods -> This would call Base.findOne()
const record = await Child.basePolicy.findOne()

//  use basePolicy -> This would base super.save()
record.basePolicy.save();
```

Is there a short way to do this?

What I want really is this, but not this verbose.. Is there a less verbose way and that will include the same typings..

```js
class Child extends Base {
  // class methods
  public static basePolicy = {
     findOne() { return super.findOne() },
     findMany() { return super.findMany() } 
  }

  // instance methods
  public basePolicy = {
     save() { return super.save() }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would need `child.basePolicy.save()` on the instance when you can do `child.save()`. Anyways, I suppose you could use `getPrototypeOf` for the static one: https://tsplay.dev/WyoogN

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help. The static way works great for me. Regarding the `child.save()` I have a specific situation where I want to expose the api of the parent, so to be able to do `child.basePolicy.save()` <- using the parent class.

Comment: So what you want is some `super` property which makes `child.super.save()` to call `superSave(){super.save()}` ?

Comment: I want a property which will contain the super api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/NrQ9Dw)

This makes any `class extends Base` have a static and instance `super` properties which allow to call `super` methods easily

(this can be extended for `grangchild` but that's harder)

```
abstract class Base {
  static staticSave(n: 3 | 1) {
    console.log(`${n}) static save of Base!`)
  }
  methodSave(n: 4 | 2) {
    console.log(`${n}) method save of Base!`)
  }

  static get super(): typeof Base { return Object.getPrototypeOf(this) }
  get super(): Base {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, prop) {
        return Object.getPrototypeOf(target.constructor.prototype)[prop]
      }
    })
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  static staticSave(n: 1) {
    console.log(`${n}) static save of Child!`)
  }
  methodSave(n: 2) {
    console.log(`${n}) method save of Child!`)
  }
}

let child = new Child();
Child.staticSave(1); // "1) static save of Child!" 
child.methodSave(2); // "2) method save of Child!" 

Child.super.staticSave(3); // "3) static save of Base!" 
child.super.methodSave(4); // "4) method save of Base!"
```

Comment: This was a fun one